# How to fill the last observations with retime in matlab?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I am interpolating variables from quarterly to monthly frequency in MATLAB. However, when I use `retime` it doesn't go as far as the end of the sample but it stops 2 months before.

Let me give you an example:

```
T = datetime(2002,01,01):calquarters:datetime(2019,12,01);

TT = timetable(T', randn(72,1))

x = retime(TT, 'monthly', 'spline') % interpolate
```

As you can see it gives me back 214 observations rather than 216, November and December 2019 are missing.
How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, but `TT` having 72 quarters instead of 73 means that you are actually storing dates from 1st January 2002 to 1st October 2019 - as the next quarter would start from 1st January 2020, which is then not included in your original array (you can check this by printing `TT` and checking if this date is included or not).

If this is the case, there is no way for `retime` to interpolate the missing months, as they aren't in the original matrix (that is, `retime` cannot interpolate from October to January, since there is no such thing in `TT`).

Replacing `datetime(2019,12,01)` with `datetime(2020,01,01)`, as well as replacing `randn(72,1)` with `randn(73,1)`, might solve your issue.

Comment: You are welcome, I hope this actually solved your problem!